# Dealing with Special Character in SQL Server Table Column Name

Tags: sql, sql-server

Actually I’ve created a SQL Server table with a column name containing special characters like `@#$$%Id%^$#` and I have created an insert query to insert value such as:

```
Insert into MyTable ([@#$$%Id%^$#]) values (@@#$$%Id%^$#)
```

After that passing parameter value as:

```
SqlCommand  cmd = new SqlCommand (“Insert into MyTable ([@#$$%Id%^$#]) values (@@#$$%Id%^$#) ”);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter (“(@@#$$%Id%^$#”, ParameterValue))
```

After executing this code I got

> *Must Declare Scalar Variable @*

Comment: Don't edit in Word and paste here (smart quotes are not that smart).

Answer (score 4):

This will never work:

```
Insert into MyTable ([@#$$%Id%^$#]) values (@@#$$%Id%^$#)
```

Unless you have declared a variable this way:

```
DECLARE @@#$$%Id%^$# INT = 1;
```

However this is not valid syntax. So perhaps you meant to insert the entire value as a string:

```
Insert into MyTable ([@#$$%Id%^$#]) values ('@@#$$%Id%^$#')
```

Your use of a leading @ in the string is confusing - are you meaning that to be a parameter designation? This works fine for me:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable([@#$$%Id%^$#] VARCHAR(255));

INSERT dbo.MyTable([@#$$%Id%^$#]) VALUES('@@#$$%Id%^$#');

DROP TABLE dbo.MyTable;
```